# How to get MSVC MergeModules v142 in VisualStudio 2022?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, wix

I work on an open-source application that is built in VisualStudio using the `v142` toolset. This toolset is choosen over the newer `v143` toolset because

- some external libraries provide binary distributions for `v142`
- github actions provide a runner containing `v142`

New developers of course start with VisualStudio 2022 CE. They just have to install the correct toolset and the compilation succeeds as expected. However, when **building the installer** (using [Wix](https://wixtoolset.org/)) it complains that the merge module for `v142` is not available:

```
error LGHT0103 : The system cannot find the file 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Redist\MSVC\14.29.30133\MergeModules\Microsoft_VC142_CRT_x86.msm'.
```

Even installing the package `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VC.Redist.MSM` via the VisualStudio installer did not bring the `v142` merge modules in. They are only available for the `v143` toolset.

- Is there some way to get the missing merge modules?
- Or would it be OK to use the `v143` merge modules while everything else is `v142`?

Find the complete list of installed packages for VS 2022 here:

```
{
  "version": "1.0",
  "components": [
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.CoreEditor",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.CoreEditor",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.TypeScript.TSServer",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentGroup.WebToolsExtensions",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.JavaScript.TypeScript",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Roslyn.Compiler",
    "Microsoft.Component.MSBuild",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Roslyn.LanguageServices",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.TextTemplating",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.NuGet",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Debugger.JustInTime",
    "Component.Microsoft.VisualStudio.LiveShare.2022",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.IntelliCode",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VC.CoreIde",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VC.Tools.x86.x64",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Graphics.Tools",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VC.DiagnosticTools",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VC.Redist.14.Latest",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentGroup.NativeDesktop.Core",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentGroup.WebToolsExtensions.CMake",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VC.CMake.Project",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VC.ATL",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VC.TestAdapterForBoostTest",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VC.TestAdapterForGoogleTest",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VC.ASAN",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Windows10SDK.18362",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentGroup.VC.Tools.142.x86.x64",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NativeDesktop",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VC.Redist.MSM",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VC.14.29.16.11.x86.x64"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This appears to be a bug in the Visual Studio 2022 installer: The merge modules component should be tied to which toolsets are installed, but it appears to install only the latest/current toolset's merge modules. The same is true for Visual Studio 2019; it appears that version is the only way to get the merge modules installed.

That said, [merge modules are not recommended.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/windows/redistributing-components-by-using-merge-modules?view=msvc-170) The preferred method is to use the [redistributable packages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/windows/redistributing-visual-cpp-files?view=msvc-170#install-the-redistributable-packages).

Comment: Providing the toolset without the runtime (in MSM form) sure feels like a bug. However if MSM is not recommended any more I will switch to redistributable packages and solve the problem that way.